# Use different local storage between windows

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have an web page that allows users to enter orders in back-end system. The web page manages all the input data with local storage (for now, I am still designing). The users have requested they have the ability to have multiple tabs or windows open, meaning each tab or window should have its own unique data stored. For example

Window 1, has order details entered for customer A123

Window 2, has order details entered for customer B987

Window N ....

So this means I need to know which tab/window is what and treat accordingly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about holding all the sessions in one browser tab but tabbed within your app?

Comment: The problem with this is, I cant stop the user from opening up another window.

Comment: What I'm starting to this is using something like http://peerjs.com/ to communicate between sessions (ideally without a 3rd party server though -although I guess you could host it).

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL parameter that identifies which client.  You can use the client id from the page's URL parameters to differentiate the local storage object names.